# Permit to mark a comment as read to avoid inbox notification

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, notifications

The inbox turns always red upon a response, even if I have already read that comment.

Consider to reduce this "noise", by permitting to mark a comment as read.

So here is the situation I considered: Deep below in a  page (where I do not see the top-bar) I see that there is a new comment, so I load the comment and read that response.

Later, I go up to the top-bar and see the red inbox, thinking that this is a new comment - so I click on the inbox. But most of the time it turns out to be the very same comment I just read.  By permitting to mark such a comment, the red notification would go away, provided that there is only this one event.

Comment: Wait, what?  If I so much as look at that red inbox, *all* of the notifications go away for a very long time.  Are you selecting the red inbox or are you looking at a specific post?

Comment: @Mak: I am looking at the top-bar to see the red inbox.

Comment: I'm not sure I can reproduce this...maybe if we had more people commenting on this question?

Comment: So you want to mark it as read while reading it in the comments section? Like this: [mark as read]

Comment: @ayhan, yes. Just like upvoting your comment.

Comment: Isn't this a lot more work (never mind the development time for the UI and notification system) than to just click your global inbox, see you've already read it and ignore it?

Comment: @false What advantage (by means of clicks) would that have vs clicking at the inbox notification header?

Comment: @πάν: It's not the clicks, it is the distraction which could be reduced. When I look at a comment, I am focused on it, so a click does not cost me much, mentally. But when I see (long thereafter) a red box, I am distracted: It's a false alarm, and I would need to click on it **and** read out of context, the first words to conclude that I have already seen that.

Comment: @Jon: See above response.

Comment: It would be nice of the system noticed you loaded the comment and marked it as read automatically. It could still be visible in the notifications menu on demand, but not as unread. Notifications, especially useless notifications, should be minimized whenever possible.

Comment: @NathanArthur: It is difficult to identify the precise moment, when a comment has been actually read. Think of the moment you load that page - do you actually read all comments on it in one fell swoop?

Comment: @false: Sorry, I wasn't clear: What I meant was that when you click "load additional comments...", it would make sense for the notifications for _those specific comments_ to be marked read. I wager it's quite unlikely a person would click the "load more comments" link and not read the additional comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure this is worth it.

It seems from the comments that a number of people are confused as to the use-case of this, so this is it:- if you're having a back-and-forth in comments, and remain on the same page just waiting for the next "1 new comment" to show up, then you can have read the comment but still get a notification.

However, I'm not sure it's worth letting you mark the comment as read - doing that would be one click, as opposed to the one click it is at the moment to open the inbox. Besides, if it's only one notification, and you know that you've just read a new comment, then you also know that's what the notification is, so you don't need to read it to make sure.

TL;DR: too much development effort, not enough return.